# Failure saving sessions data

Tags: php, session, cookies, yii

i'm trying to set a life time to the `cookie` sessions in my `yii` application
in the `main.confg` file i added the following ...

```
'session' => array(
  'class' => 'CCacheHttpSession',
  'cacheID' => 'cache',
  'timeout' => 604800, // 7 days
  'sessionName' => 'zii_s',
  'cookieParams' => array(
    'domain' => '***',
    'path' => '/',
    'httponly' => true,
   'lifetime' => 100000,//this field 

  ),
),
```

***as soon as the life time value is set the session is not saved but when i remove it or setting its value to ZERO the session is saved***

*Update: the set cookie flag exists in the HTTP response and its 
Set-Cookie:zii_s=j0scslhn7q3s0fib4gns3etl01; expires=Thu, 05-Jul-2012 16:00:54 GMT; path=/; domain=***; HttpOnly*

can anyone tell me why ?

Comment: the problem may be with the `CHttpSession` configuration

Comment: there are no configurations for 'CHttpSession' in my config file ...

Comment: did you try `'lifetime'=>'100000'` instead of `'lifetime' => 100000`?

Comment: sadly yes ... it didn't work either ....

Comment: ok, i've added the cookie tag. +1

Comment: Thanks alot my friend, I'm trying to find the answer too

Comment: You may have an autostart session started? Please check your php.ini